# Different eigenvectors are obtained for lower and upper input in zheev in lapack

Tags: fortran, lapack, blas

In the following program, if I change the 'L' (Read the lower triangular part of the matrix) to 'U' (Upper triangular input) in zheev, I found the output eigenvectors are different. Anyone help ?

```
  program zheev_test
  INTEGER          N
  PARAMETER        ( N = 4 )
  INTEGER          LDA
  PARAMETER        ( LDA = N )
  INTEGER          LWMAX
  PARAMETER        ( LWMAX = 1000 )

  INTEGER          INFO, LWORK

  DOUBLE PRECISION W( N ), RWORK( 3*N-2 )
  COMPLEX*16       A( LDA, N ), WORK( LWMAX ),vect(n,n)


 a(1,:)=[( 9.14,0.00),(-4.37,-9.22),(-1.98,-1.72),(-8.96,-9.50)]
 a(2,:)=[(-4.37,9.22),(-3.35,0.00),(2.25,-9.51),(2.57,2.40)]
 a(3,:)=[(-1.98,1.72),(2.25,9.51),(-4.82,0.00),(-3.24,2.04)]
 a(4,:)=[(-8.96,9.50),(2.57,-2.40),(-3.24,-2.04),(8.44,0.00)]

 WRITE(*,*)'ZHEEV Example Program Results'

 LWORK = -1
 CALL ZHEEV( 'V', 'L', N, A, LDA, W, WORK, LWORK, RWORK,INFO )
 LWORK = MIN( LWMAX, INT( WORK( 1 ) ) )

  CALL ZHEEV( 'V', 'L', N, A, LDA, W, WORK, LWORK, RWORK,INFO )

  IF(info>0) stop 'The algorithm failed to compute eigenvalues.'

  write(*,*) w
  write(*,*) a(:,1)

  end program
```

Comment: Interesting combination of Fortran 2003 and some old 77 style.

Answer (score 2):

I guess this is probably because of different phases of the eigenvectors (which are determined only up to complex multiplicative factors). To avoid this, it may be useful to divide the whole eigenvector, e.g., by the first element such that

```
write(*,*) a(:,1) / a(1,1)
```

Then we obtain (with ifort14)

```
 For mode = 'L':
 eigenvalues = -16.0047467285727  -6.76497034056390  6.66571163878665 25.5140052777621     

 a(:,1) =  ( 0.344765913149177,  0.000000000000000E+000)
           ( 0.441821763159905, -0.538931962007287)
           (-0.479504340748548, -0.374404626123115)
           ( 0.100522573509652, -0.123589281135427)

 a(:,1) / a(1,1) =  ( 1.00000000000000,   0.000000000000000E+000)
                    ( 1.28151231403417,  -1.56318226788881)
                    (-1.39081133737566,  -1.08596764309792)
                    ( 0.291567610589614, -0.358473028863359)

 For mode = 'U':
 eigenvalues = -16.0047467285727 -6.76497034056390  6.66571163878665  25.5140052777620

 a(:,1) =  ( 0.217545360791378,       0.267465046067210)
           ( 0.696883676007484,       2.696699658290103E-003)
           (-1.210616849344158E-002, -0.608240641147479)
           ( 0.159308186219588,       0.000000000000000E+000)

 a(:,1) / a(1,1) =  ( 1.00000000000000,   0.000000000000000E+000)
                    ( 1.28151231403417,  -1.56318226788881)
                    (-1.39081133737566,  -1.08596764309792)
                    ( 0.291567610589614, -0.358473028863359)
```

which agrees with the result obtained from other software (but only within single precision, because your `a` matrix is set with single-precision literals!)

```
eigenvalues = -16.004746472094745 -6.764970154793344 6.665711453507093 25.514005173380916

V[1,1] / V[1,1] =  1.0                 - 0.0im
V[2,1] / V[1,1] =  1.281512342601922   - 1.5631822174403054im
V[3,1] / V[1,1] = -1.3908112850832561  - 1.0859676556672477im
V[4,1] / V[1,1] =  0.29156759974571633 - 0.35847302874950293im
```

Comment: Thanks. Yes, these vectors in fact are the same. In the lapack, I think the eigenvectors should be the normalization ones, namely, nq=sum(conjg(a(:,1))*a(:,1) )=(1.0,0.0). In this way, the phases of the eigenvectors can be fixed. But, I found, in the "Lower" case and "Upper"  case obey this ruler. So, why still the phase problems ?

Comment: If u(:) is a normalized eigenvector (A * u = lambda * u), then v(:) = exp(i * phi) * u(:) with arbitrary real phi is also a normalized eigenvector of A . So, depending on the way to calculate the eigenvector (here, the choice of 'L' or 'U' mode), I guess the resulting eigenvector differs by this exp(i * phi) factor. This arbitrary phase factor cannot be removed by the normalization of each eigenvector (as far as I understand...)

Comment: [To make the phase more clear (and retain the normalization), it may be better to divide by a(1,1) / abs(a(1,1)). This makes the first element of the vector real-valued. Similarly, we can divide by a(k,1)/abs(a(k,1)) for any k (as long as a(k,1) not equal to 0), which corresponds to a different choice of "phi" (phase factor).]

Comment: It looks like the source code of [zheev](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zheev.f.html) and [zungtr](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zungtr.f.html#ZUNGTR.1) (which is called from zheev) performs different operations depending on 'L' and 'U', so probably resulting in different phases of eigenvectors (even with normalization).

Comment: Thanks for the details. OK, I will try to find some documents for lapack. I think this point should be explained.